# Unrelated branches while creating pull request in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm new to git..
while creating pull request it is showing Unrelated branches
please help me regarding this

Comment: can you rephrase your question, what is your issue, what do you need help with ?

Comment: maybe this could be an answer to your question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837176/unable-to-merge-unrelated-branches-in-bitbucket